# SIGABRT - What is happening? Label of Death

Tags: sigabrt

I am coding an app that involves loading data from NSUserDefaults. So when I have confirmed that the passed integer was 1, I want it to display a certain text. However when I don't have a UILabel on my .Xib. It is fine, but as soon as I add a outlet for the label, place it onto the .Xib and link it all up, it comes up with SIGABRT

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

int page = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Page"] integerValue];

NSString *log = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", page];

NSLog(log);

if (page == 1 ) {
    NSLog(@"redstone block");
title.text = @"redstone Blcok";
}


[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

The error I get:

2013-04-09 18:16:13.910 redstoneGuide[94905:c07] -[UILabel copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x756b910
2013-04-09 18:16:13.911 redstoneGuide[94905:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x756b910'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1599012 0x12a6e7e 0x16244bd 0x1588bbc 0x158894e 0x12baae9 0x2cd32b 0xcd45be 0xcd40e7 0xcfeb58 0x408019 0x12ba663 0x159445a 0x406b1c 0x2cb7e7 0x2cbdc8 0x2cbff8 0x2cc232 0x2d7c25 0x4d73a3 0x2d4ee3 0x2d5167 0x33cc 0x12ba705 0x1ee2c0 0x1ee258 0x2af021 0x2af57f 0x2ae6e8 0x4b21d3 0x1561afe 0x1561a3d 0x153f7c2 0x153ef44 0x153ee1b 0x25fa7e3 0x25fa668 0x1eaffc 0x1fcd 0x1ef5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you cannot do

```
Iboutlet uilabel *title;
```

The name title causes the application to crash.
However, the below works.

```
Iboutlet uilabel *Gtitle
```